# Prevent tooltip/div from going offscreen/out of browser chrome on mouseover/hover

Tags: jquery

I'm using jquery to add and remove a class to have an informative tooltip pop up when I hover over a thumbnail but when the thumbnail is too close to the edge of the browser chrome the tooltip goes outside the chrome and isn't readable. Any ideas on where to start to have the tooltip remain on screen? Thanks for any suggestions. Here is the code:

http://jsfiddle.net/ySeTL/

Comment: qTip: [link](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/) is built off of jquery and has support for this kind of functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/ySeTL/10/

**full screen**
http://jsfiddle.net/loktar/ySeTL/10/embedded/result/

Basically that just doesn't show it if it will be out of bounds. The next step would be to have an else, that positions the element you are displaying so many pixels to the left.

Im confused by your markup a bit. Looks like you have all the things your showing as individual elements. IE title, pic, description are all separate hidden elements. I would wrap a container around all of them, then hide/show that, and position that.

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I've used a position calculating algo to determine the position of the popup prior to displaying it.  You'll have to determine the position, width, and height of the popup node, then compare it against the document dimensions.  If it falls outside of the boundaries, then you reposition it before calling the class change function.